# getJSONObject(int) is undefined for the type JSONArray

Tags: arrays, json

I am getting an JSON array in response from rest webservice and I want to iterate over it to get the various attributes of it. There are multiple json array with the same name and only the attributes values and different. For this I have tried various code snippets. I have mentioned all my tried code snippets with the error I got.

```
   ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.exchange("xyz.com",
            HttpMethod.GET, entity, String.class);
    JSONParser parser=new JSONParser();
    System.out.println("Response is"+response.getBody());

    try{
        //JSONObject outerObject = (JSONObject)parser.parse(response.getBody()); Class Cast Exception
          //JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(response.getBody()); jsonobject must begin with {
        JSONArray jsonArray = (JSONArray) parser.parse(response.getBody());
        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.size(); i++)
        {                 
              /*JSONObject object = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);*/// getJSONObject(int) is undefined for the type JSONArray

        }
    }catch (ParseException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

The Webservices response is like

```
[
{"mutualFund":{"fundCode":"xyz","fundName":"123","isin":"IE000"}},
{"mutualFund":{"fundCode":"xyz","fundName":"123","isin":"xyz"}},
{"mutualFund":{"fundCode":"xyz","fundName":"123","sedol":"WB1"}}
 ]
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use Parser, becuase json array constructor takes string as paramter

Download the following [JSON lib](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/j/Downloadjavajsonjar.htm) to make the json easy to parse

```
 ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.exchange("xyz.com",
            HttpMethod.GET, entity, String.class);

    System.out.println("Response is"+response.getBody());

    try{
        JSONArray outerObject = new JSONArray(response.getBody());

       for(JSONObject object: outerObject)
{
// Your Logic
}
    }catch (ParseException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: The constructor JSONArray(String) is undefined error is coming

Comment: org.json.simple.JSONArray;

Comment: Don't use simple wait a second i will provide you with the correct lib

Comment: This is my dependency in pom.xml <dependency>
   <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
   <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
   <version>1.1</version>
  </dependency>

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142576/discussion-between-basil-battikhi-and-java-developers).

Comment: I have included that jar and now using org.json.JSONArray but now I am getting error "Can only iterate over an array or an instance of java.lang.Iterable" in for loop

Comment: I'm not sure of why you are getting this error! did you use the same lib for both ? if so use a normal for loop instade of for each